# Add an entity to a doctrine PersistentCollection on a ManytoMany without causing Duplicate Entry Integrity Constraint violations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I have two entities - users and counties.

Many users can have many counties and vice versa, ie it's a many to many relationship:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="county")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CountyRepository")
 */
class County
{
    /**
     * Many counties can have many users assigned
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="counties")
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users): void
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table("users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * Many users can be assigned to many counties
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\County", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_counties")
     */
    protected $counties;

    /**
     * @param County $county
     */
    public function addCounty(County $county)
    {
        if (empty($this->getCounties())) {
            $this->setCounties([$county]);
        } else {
            if (!$this->getCounties()
                      ->contains($county)) {
                $this->getCounties()
                     ->add($county)
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return PersistentCollection|null
     */
    public function getCounties()
    {
        return $this->counties;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $counties
     */
    public function setCounties($counties): void
    {
        $this->counties = $counties;
    }
}
```

Note the `addCounty()` method on the `User` entity.

All I want is for an entity to be added to the collection if it isn't already part of it.

I am doing it that way instead of:

```php
/**
 * @param County $county
 */
public function addCounty(County $county)
{
    $this->county[] = $county
    // OR
    $this->getCounties()->add($county)
}
```

As these ways cause SQL errors such as:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '42-22' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Now - the error makes sense and I get how to go about avoiding it, as demonstrated above.

However, I feel that this must surely be a common challenge in dorctrine's `ManytoMany` relationships so I am wondering if there is a better way to go about it to get doctrine to handle this implicitly behind the scenes?

Note - I have seen the "[Symfony doctrine Many to Many Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410217/symfony-doctrine-many-to-many-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-ent)" answer, but it just feels like there should be a better way to go about this and get doctrine to handle this auto-magically :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above method:

```
public function addCounty(County $county)
{
    if (empty($this->getCounties())) {
        $this->setCounties([$county]);
    } else {
        if (!$this->getCounties()
                  ->contains($county)) {
            $this->getCounties()
                 ->add($county)
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [doctrine doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/faq.html#mapping):

> Doctrine does not check if you are re-adding entities with a primary key that already exists or adding entities to a collection twice. You have to check for both conditions yourself in the code before calling $em->flush() if you know that unique constraint failures can occur.

So you are correctly checking if the entity is already part of the collection on the **owning side** and if not, you add it.

That said there is an **alternative way** to do this with **less lines of code** by using [indexBy](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html#mapping-indexed-associations) attribute:

```
 /**
 * Many users can be assigned to many counties
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\County", inversedBy="users", indexBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_counties")
 */
protected $counties;
```

So **indexBy="id"** for the collection and then you can:

```
public function addCounty(County $county)
{
    $this->counties[$county->getId()] = $county;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/**
* @param County $county
*/
public function addCounty(County $county)
{
    // Here you make sure that the $county is removed if it where present
    $this->counties->removeElement($county);

    // Now you add it
    $this->counties->add($county);
}
```